# Does anyone know of any open source versions of Twitter?

Tags: c#, web-applications, open-source, twitter

I built a GIS application around Twitter and now its getting some interest.
But one of the requirements is that they don't want any outside dependencies.
So I'll need to mimic Twitters functions.

Anyone know of any open source Twitter projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jaiku](http://www.jaiku.com/) is a microblogging service very similar to Twitter. Google bought Jaiku a few years ago and made its engine open source. You can find it here:

http://code.google.com/p/jaikuengine/

If you're looking for a .NET alternative. There is [Yonkly](http://yonkly.com/). Is an open source Twitter clone written using ASP.NET MVC. You can find the source here:

http://www.codeplex.com/yonkly

Answer (score 7):

Laconica?

http://laconi.ca/trac/

Identica demos it nicely:

http://identi.ca/

Comment: Do you know of any that uses .NET?

Answer (score 1):

I have used laconi.ca in the past, it is easy to figure out and highly customizable (for how young it is).